# How to calculate correlation between 2 vectors which have the dimension (1000, 10000, 3) using python?

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis, correlation

I want to find the correlation between the velocity and orientation of some particles. I have the velocity vector data with the shape `(Ntime, Npart, 3)` where `Ntime` is the number of time steps, `Npart` is the number of particles and 3 is the component of velocity.

For orientation, I have a position vector which let me know the direction of the longest axis of the particle. It has the same shape as the velocity i.e. `(Ntime, Npart, 3)`.

I would like to see if their is a correlation between the orientation and the velocity of the particles, at each `Ntime`. So the correlation should have a shape of `(Ntime, Npart)`.

I know I can use `np.corrcoef()[0,1]` but with the size of data I have it takes a lot of time to compute.

Is there a way this can efficiently vectorized to make it fast?